# Como puedo hacer un . map a todo un objecto

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

como va?me quede trabado en este problema, lo que ando intentando es imprimir unicamente todas las fechas registrada de la api:

Foto de consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego tengo que intentar imprimir todo los datos de total_cases:
example: [5,4,6,12,50]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ahora mi codigo es este:

```js
 const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0];

<Line
      data={{
        labels: datos.map((diasMes) => {
          return diasMes; // solo me imprime [obejct Obeject]
        }),
        datasets: [
          {
            data: datos.map((loscasos) => {
              return loscasos['3/14/20'].total_cases; // solo imprime un solo dato,
              // y la idea es que me impre todo los datos de total_cases
            }),
            label: 'Infected',
            borderColor: '#3333ff',
            fill: true,
          },
        ],
      }}
    />
```

Actualización, lo que he intentado , por ahora:

```js
datos[Object.keys(datos)[0]].total_cases,
datos[Object.keys(datos)[6]].total_cases,
datoss.map((item) => item[Object.keys(item)[1]].total_cases),
```

todavia no logro traer todo los dato de total cases

Comment: He conseguido tener, todo las fechas con  Object.keys(diasMes); , ahora solo me queda conseguir todos los total_case

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(el objeto)) o puedes usar console.table(el objeto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar las keys del objeto `datos`. Las keys serían las fechas y en el `map` con la key puedes acceder al objeto por key y asi acceder a los datos de ese objeto.

Para que te quede mas claro porque no se lo que estas intentando.

```js
const datos = {
    "3/06/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 3,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
    "3/07/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 1,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
    "3/08/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 0,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
}

const dias = Object.keys(datos);
// como ves imprime los dias
console.log(dias);
// imprime casos por dia
console.log('total_cases', dias.map((dia) => datos[dia].total_cases))
```

```
//const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0];
// objeto de ejemplo

const datos = {
    "3/06/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 3,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
    "3/07/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 3,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
    "3/08/20": {
        new_daily_cases: 2,
        new_daily_deaths: 0,
        total_cases: 3,
        total_deaths: 0,
        total_recovery: 1,
    },
}
const dias = Object.keys(datos);
const chartOptions = {
    labels: dias,
    datasets: [
        {
            data: dias.map((dia) => datos[dia].total_cases),
            label: 'Infected',
            borderColor: '#3333ff',
            fill: true,
        },
        {
            // accedes la propiedad que quieras mostrar en la grafica
            data: dias.map((dia) => datos[dia].total_deaths),
            label: 'Deaths',
            borderColor: '#3333ff',
            fill: true,
        },
    ],
}

<Line
    data={chartOptions}
/>
```

Tienes que entender que `map` al fin al cabo es un `for-loop` pero en vez de recorrer los elementos de manera tradicional con el indice con `map` le pasa el `callback` que indica lo que quieres hacer con cada elemento del array.

Al final `map` siempre devuelve un array nuevo.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Comment: Hola como va, aparentemente Object.keys(datos) no me funciona por que me coloca todas las fechas en un solo formato string :(

Comment: puedes poner el objeto `datos` en tu pregunta. Para ver que pasa

Comment: Listo, actualizado...

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta sinceramente no entiendo lo que has intentado

Comment: Mi forma de solucionarlo fue Object.values(datos).map(item => item.total_cases), pero igual manera gracias. +1